# Logstash conf error - amazon_es

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, aws-elasticsearch

I am trying to configure for the first time my logstash.conf file with an output to amazon_es.

My whole *logstash.conf* file is here:

```
input {
  jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"
    # The user we wish to execute our statement as
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "root"
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => "/mnt/c/Users/xxxxxxxx/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    # our query
    statement => "SELECT * FROM testtable"
    }
  }
output {
  amazon_es {
    hosts => ["search-xxxxx.eu-west-3.es.amazonaws.com"]
    region => "eu-west-3"
    aws_access_key_id => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    aws_secret_access_key => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    index => "test-migrate"
    document_type => "data"
    }
}
```

I have 3 elements selected from my database, but the first time i run the script, only the first element is indexed in elastic search. The second time i run it, all 3 elements are indexed. I get the error each time i run logstash with this conf file.

EDIT 2:

```
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,270][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,279][DEBUG][logstash.plugins.registry] Adding plugin to the registry {:name=>"fb_apache", :type=>:modules, :class=>#<LogStash::Modules::Scaffold:0x47c515a1 @module_name="fb_apache", @directory="/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/modules/fb_apache/configuration", @kibana_version_parts=["6", "0", "0"]>}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,286][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/modules/netflow/configuration"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,287][DEBUG][logstash.plugins.registry] Adding plugin to the registry {:name=>"netflow", :type=>:modules, :class=>#<LogStash::Modules::Scaffold:0x6f1a5910 @module_name="netflow", @directory="/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/modules/netflow/configuration", @kibana_version_parts=["6", "0", "0"]>}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,765][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] -------- Logstash Settings (* means modified) ---------
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,765][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] node.name: "DEVFE-AMT"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,766][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] *path.config: "logstash.conf"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,766][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] path.data: "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/data"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,767][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] modules.cli: []
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,768][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] modules: []
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,768][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] modules_setup: false
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,768][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.test_and_exit: false
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,769][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.reload.automatic: false
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,769][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.reload.interval: 3000000000
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,769][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.support_escapes: false
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,770][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] metric.collect: true
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,770][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.id: "main"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,771][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.system: false
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,771][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.workers: 8
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,771][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.output.workers: 1
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,772][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.batch.size: 125
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,772][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.batch.delay: 50
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,772][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.unsafe_shutdown: false
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,772][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.java_execution: false
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,773][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.reloadable: true
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,773][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] path.plugins: []
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,773][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.debug: false
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,776][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] *log.level: "debug" (default: "info")
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,783][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] version: false
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,784][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] help: false
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,784][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] log.format: "plain"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,786][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] http.host: "127.0.0.1"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,793][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] http.port: 9600..9700
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,793][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] http.environment: "production"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,794][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.type: "memory"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,796][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.drain: false
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,804][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.page_capacity: 67108864
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,809][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.max_bytes: 1073741824
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,822][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.max_events: 0
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,823][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.checkpoint.acks: 1024
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,836][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.checkpoint.writes: 1024
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,837][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.checkpoint.interval: 1000
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,846][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] dead_letter_queue.enable: false
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,854][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] dead_letter_queue.max_bytes: 1073741824
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,859][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] slowlog.threshold.warn: -1
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,868][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] slowlog.threshold.info: -1
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,873][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] slowlog.threshold.debug: -1
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,885][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] slowlog.threshold.trace: -1
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,887][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] keystore.classname: "org.logstash.secret.store.backend.JavaKeyStore"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,896][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] keystore.file: "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/config/logstash.keystore"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,896][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] path.queue: "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/data/queue"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,911][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] path.dead_letter_queue: "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/data/dead_letter_queue"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,911][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] path.settings: "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/config"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,926][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] path.logs: "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/logs"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,926][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] --------------- Logstash Settings -------------------
    [2018-02-08T14:31:18,998][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
    [2018-02-08T14:31:19,067][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Setting up metric collection
    [2018-02-08T14:31:19,147][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.os] Starting {:polling_interval=>5, :polling_timeout=>120}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:19,293][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] Starting {:polling_interval=>5, :polling_timeout=>120}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:19,422][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:19,429][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:19,453][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.persistentqueue] Starting {:polling_interval=>5, :polling_timeout=>120}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:19,464][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.deadletterqueue] Starting {:polling_interval=>5, :polling_timeout=>120}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:19,519][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.2.0"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:19,537][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Starting agent
    [2018-02-08T14:31:19,565][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Starting puma
    [2018-02-08T14:31:19,580][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Trying to start WebServer {:port=>9600}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:19,654][DEBUG][logstash.config.source.local.configpathloader] Skipping the following files while reading config since they don't match the specified glob pattern {:files=>["/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/CONTRIBUTORS", "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/Gemfile", "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/Gemfile.lock", "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/LICENSE", "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/NOTICE.TXT", "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/bin", "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/config", "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/data", "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/lib", "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/logs", "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/logstash-core", "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/logstash-core-plugin-api", "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/modules", "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/tools", "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/vendor"]}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:19,658][DEBUG][logstash.api.service     ] [api-service] start
    [2018-02-08T14:31:19,662][DEBUG][logstash.config.source.local.configpathloader] Reading config file {:config_file=>"/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/l/logstash-6.2.0/logstash.conf"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:19,770][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Converging pipelines state {:actions_count=>1}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:19,776][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Executing action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:19,948][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,157][DEBUG][logstash.plugins.registry] On demand adding plugin to the registry {:name=>"jdbc", :type=>"input", :class=>LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,557][DEBUG][logstash.plugins.registry] On demand adding plugin to the registry {:name=>"plain", :type=>"codec", :class=>LogStash::Codecs::Plain}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,580][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.plain    ] config LogStash::Codecs::Plain/@id = "plain_32fc0754-0187-437b-9d4d-2611eaba9a45"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,581][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.plain    ] config LogStash::Codecs::Plain/@enable_metric = true
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,581][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.plain    ] config LogStash::Codecs::Plain/@charset = "UTF-8"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,612][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@jdbc_connection_string = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,613][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@jdbc_user = "root"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,616][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@jdbc_password = <password>
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,623][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@jdbc_driver_library = "/mnt/c/Users/anthony.maffert/Desktop/DocumentsUbuntu/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,624][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@jdbc_driver_class = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,631][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@statement = "SELECT * FROM testtable"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,633][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@id = "ff7529f734e0813846bc8e3b2bcf0794d99ff5cb61b947e0497922b083b3851a"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,647][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@enable_metric = true
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,659][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@codec = <LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_32fc0754-0187-437b-9d4d-2611eaba9a45", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,663][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@add_field = {}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,663][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@jdbc_paging_enabled = false
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,678][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@jdbc_page_size = 100000
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,679][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@jdbc_validate_connection = false
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,693][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@jdbc_validation_timeout = 3600
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,694][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@jdbc_pool_timeout = 5
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,708][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@sequel_opts = {}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,708][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@sql_log_level = "info"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,715][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@connection_retry_attempts = 1
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,716][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@connection_retry_attempts_wait_time = 0.5
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,721][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@parameters = {}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,723][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@last_run_metadata_path = "/home/maffer_a/.logstash_jdbc_last_run"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,731][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@use_column_value = false
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,731][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@tracking_column_type = "numeric"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,745][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@clean_run = false
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,746][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@record_last_run = true
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,808][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@lowercase_column_names = true
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,808][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] config LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc/@columns_charset = {}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,830][DEBUG][logstash.plugins.registry] On demand adding plugin to the registry {:name=>"stdout", :type=>"output", :class=>LogStash::Outputs::Stdout}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,893][DEBUG][logstash.plugins.registry] On demand adding plugin to the registry {:name=>"json_lines", :type=>"codec", :class=>LogStash::Codecs::JSONLines}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,901][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.jsonlines] config LogStash::Codecs::JSONLines/@id = "json_lines_e27ae5ff-5352-4061-9415-c75234fafc91"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,902][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.jsonlines] config LogStash::Codecs::JSONLines/@enable_metric = true
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,902][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.jsonlines] config LogStash::Codecs::JSONLines/@charset = "UTF-8"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,905][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.jsonlines] config LogStash::Codecs::JSONLines/@delimiter = "\n"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,915][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.stdout  ] config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@codec = <LogStash::Codecs::JSONLines id=>"json_lines_e27ae5ff-5352-4061-9415-c75234fafc91", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8", delimiter=>"\n">
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,924][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.stdout  ] config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@id = "4fb47c5631fa87c6a839a6f476077e9fa55456c479eee7251568f325435f3bbc"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,929][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.stdout  ] config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@enable_metric = true
    [2018-02-08T14:31:21,939][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.stdout  ] config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@workers = 1
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,217][DEBUG][logstash.plugins.registry] On demand adding plugin to the registry {:name=>"amazon_es", :type=>"output", :class=>LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,287][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.plain    ] config LogStash::Codecs::Plain/@id = "plain_673a059d-4236-4f10-ba64-43ee33e050e4"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,288][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.plain    ] config LogStash::Codecs::Plain/@enable_metric = true
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,288][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.plain    ] config LogStash::Codecs::Plain/@charset = "UTF-8"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,294][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@hosts = ["search-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.eu-west-3.es.amazonaws.com"]
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,294][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@region = "eu-west-3"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,295][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@aws_access_key_id = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,295][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@aws_secret_access_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,296][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@index = "test-migrate"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,299][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@document_type = "data"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,299][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@id = "7c6401c2f72c63f8d359a42a2f440a663303cb2cbfefff8fa32d64a6f571a527"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,306][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@enable_metric = true
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,310][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@codec = <LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_673a059d-4236-4f10-ba64-43ee33e050e4", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,310][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@workers = 1
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,310][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@manage_template = true
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,317][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@template_name = "logstash"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,325][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@template_overwrite = false
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,326][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@port = 443
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,332][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@protocol = "https"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,333][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@flush_size = 500
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,335][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@idle_flush_time = 1
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,340][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@action = "index"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,341][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@path = "/"
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,341][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@max_retries = 3
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,341][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@retry_max_items = 5000
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,342][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@retry_max_interval = 5
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,342][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@doc_as_upsert = false
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,342][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] config LogStash::Outputs::AmazonES/@upsert = ""
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,426][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,476][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] Normalizing http path {:path=>"/", :normalized=>"/"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,791][INFO ][logstash.outputs.amazones] Automatic template management enabled {:manage_template=>"true"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:23,835][INFO ][logstash.outputs.amazones] Using mapping template {:template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"_all"=>{"enabled"=>true, "omit_norms"=>true}, "dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"string", "index"=>"analyzed", "omit_norms"=>true}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"string", "index"=>"analyzed", "omit_norms"=>true, "fields"=>{"raw"=>{"type"=>"string", "index"=>"not_analyzed", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@version"=>{"type"=>"string", "index"=>"not_analyzed"}, "geoip"=>{"type"=>"object", "dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}}}}}}}}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:24,480][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:24,482][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:25,242][ERROR][logstash.outputs.amazones] Failed to install template: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [string] declared on field [@version]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: No handler for type [string] declared on field [@version]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [string] declared on field [@version]"}},"status":400}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:25,246][INFO ][logstash.outputs.amazones] New Elasticsearch output {:hosts=>["search-XXXXXXXXXXXX.eu-west-3.es.amazonaws.com"], :port=>443}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:25,619][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started succesfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x42da9cf8 run>"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:25,712][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :pipelines=>["main"]}
    Thu Feb 08 14:31:26 GMT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
    [2018-02-08T14:31:26,716][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (0.008417s) SELECT version()
    [2018-02-08T14:31:26,858][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (0.002332s) SELECT count(*) AS `count` FROM (SELECT * FROM testtable) AS `t1` LIMIT 1
    [2018-02-08T14:31:26,863][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] Executing JDBC query {:statement=>"SELECT * FROM testtable", :parameters=>{:sql_last_value=>2018-02-08 14:23:01 UTC}, :count=>3}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:26,873][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (0.000842s) SELECT * FROM testtable
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,022][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] Closing {:plugin=>"LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,023][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] filter received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2018-02-08T14:31:26.918Z, "personid"=>4004, "city"=>"Cape Town", "@version"=>"1", "firstname"=>"Richard", "lastname"=>"Baron"}}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,023][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] filter received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2018-02-08T14:31:26.919Z, "personid"=>4003, "city"=>"Cape Town", "@version"=>"1", "firstname"=>"Sharon", "lastname"=>"McWell"}}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,023][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] filter received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2018-02-08T14:31:26.890Z, "personid"=>4005, "city"=>"Cape Town", "@version"=>"1", "firstname"=>"Jaques", "lastname"=>"Kallis"}}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,032][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] output received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2018-02-08T14:31:26.918Z, "personid"=>4004, "city"=>"Cape Town", "@version"=>"1", "firstname"=>"Richard", "lastname"=>"Baron"}}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,035][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] output received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2018-02-08T14:31:26.890Z, "personid"=>4005, "city"=>"Cape Town", "@version"=>"1", "firstname"=>"Jaques", "lastname"=>"Kallis"}}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,040][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] output received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2018-02-08T14:31:26.919Z, "personid"=>4003, "city"=>"Cape Town", "@version"=>"1", "firstname"=>"Sharon", "lastname"=>"McWell"}}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,047][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] Pushing flush onto pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x42da9cf8 sleep>"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,053][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] Shutting down filter/output workers {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x42da9cf8 run>"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,062][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] Pushing shutdown {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x3f1899bb@[main]>worker0 run>"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,069][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] Pushing shutdown {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x41529ca4@[main]>worker1 run>"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,070][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] Pushing shutdown {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x1c56e6d6@[main]>worker2 run>"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,083][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] Pushing shutdown {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x2f767b45@[main]>worker3 sleep>"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,083][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] Pushing shutdown {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x2017b165@[main]>worker4 run>"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,098][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] Pushing shutdown {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x65923ecd@[main]>worker5 sleep>"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,099][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] Pushing shutdown {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x1714b839@[main]>worker6 run>"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,113][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] Pushing shutdown {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0xcbee48c@[main]>worker7 run>"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,116][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] Shutdown waiting for worker thread {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x3f1899bb@[main]>worker0 run>"}
    {"@timestamp":"2018-02-08T14:31:26.919Z","personid":4003,"city":"Cape Town","@version":"1","firstname":"Sharon","lastname":"McWell"}
    {"@timestamp":"2018-02-08T14:31:26.918Z","personid":4004,"city":"Cape Town","@version":"1","firstname":"Richard","lastname":"Baron"}
    {"@timestamp":"2018-02-08T14:31:26.890Z","personid":4005,"city":"Cape Town","@version":"1","firstname":"Jaques","lastname":"Kallis"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,153][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] Shutdown waiting for worker thread {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x41529ca4@[main]>worker1 run>"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,158][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] Shutdown waiting for worker thread {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x1c56e6d6@[main]>worker2 run>"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,200][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.amazones] Flushing output {:outgoing_count=>1, :time_since_last_flush=>1.927723, :outgoing_events=>{nil=>[["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"test-migrate", :_type=>"data", :_routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0x1bacf548>]]}, :batch_timeout=>1, :force=>nil, :final=>nil}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,207][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] Shutdown waiting for worker thread {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x2f767b45@[main]>worker3 sleep>"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,251][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.os] Stopping
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,271][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] Stopping
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,273][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.persistentqueue] Stopping
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,281][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.deadletterqueue] Stopping
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,356][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Shutting down all pipelines {:pipelines_count=>1}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,362][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Converging pipelines state {:actions_count=>1}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,363][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Executing action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Stop/pipeline_id:main}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,385][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] Stopping inputs {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x42da9cf8 sleep>"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,389][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] Stopping {:plugin=>"LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc"}
    [2018-02-08T14:31:27,399][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] Stopped inputs {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x42da9cf8 sleep>"}
```

Comment: You need to use version 6.x of Logstash as you're probably using version 6.x of Amazon ES, and hence, the template that Logstash tries to install is not compatible anymore (i.e. there is no `string` type anymore in ES 6

Comment: The point is that I am using the version 6.2 of logstash

Comment: What do you get when you run `GET _template` on your Amazon ES cluster?

Comment: I get empty brackets {}

Comment: Can you run this and tell me what you get `bin/logstash-plugin list --verbose | grep elasticsearch`

Comment: `[/m/c/U/a/l/logstash-6.2.0]
 »»»» bin/logstash-plugin list --verbose | grep elasticsearch `
 
`logstash-filter-elasticsearch (3.3.0)
logstash-input-elasticsearch (4.2.0)
logstash-output-elasticsearch (9.0.2)`

Comment: Can you also provide the following last piece of info (and update your question with it so it's more legible): run logstash with the `--debug` flag and share the output. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try to add the index template yourself. Copy this [ES 6.x template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/master/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template-es6x.json) on your local file system and then add the `template` setting to your `amazon_es` output, it should work:

```
  amazon_es {
    hosts => ["search-xxxxx.eu-west-3.es.amazonaws.com"]
    region => "eu-west-3"
    aws_access_key_id => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    aws_secret_access_key => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    index => "test-migrate"
    document_type => "data"
    template => '/path/to/template.json'
  }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!