# Forward logs with logstash running in ec2 instance to Amazon Elasticsearch service

Tags: logstash, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm currently running logstash in an ec2 instance with the default linux AMI, and attempting to send logs to an AWS ES instance. If I used the standard 'elasticsearch' output, I can send unsigned data to the AWS ES instance, but I'm trying to set up a prod-ready framework, and everything I've read recommends using the AWS labs logstash output plugin here( https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-output-amazon_es ).

I can confirm the plugin is installed, but when I run logstash using the below conf file, I get a message that 'Sending Logstash's logs to /var/log/logstash which is now configured via log4j2.properties', but no data appears in my elasticsearch endpoint with the '/_search?pretty=true' flag when I refresh after making a stdin entry.

```js
input {
   stdin {
        
    }
}
output {
    amazon_es {
        hosts => ["https://search-secretstuff.es.amazonaws.com"]
        region => "xxxxx"
        aws_access_key_id => 'xxxxxx'
        aws_secret_access_key => 'xxxxxx'
        index => "prod-logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        template => "/etc/logstash/mappings/es6-template.json"
    }
}
```

In addition to using stdin, I've tried using a file input, ex

```js
input {
    file {
        path => "/var/log/amazon/ssm/errors.log"
    }
}
```

The template I'm using is below, as per the accepted answer for this post ([Logstash conf error - amazon_es](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682000/logstash-conf-error-amazon-es))

```js
{
  "template" : "logstash-*",
  "version" : 60001,
  "settings" : {
    "index.refresh_interval" : "5s"
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
      "dynamic_templates" : [ {
        "message_field" : {
          "path_match" : "message",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "norms" : false
          }
        }
      }, {
        "string_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "text", "norms" : false,
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 }
            }
          }
        }
      } ],
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp": { "type": "date"},
        "@version": { "type": "keyword"},
        "geoip"  : {
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties" : {
            "ip": { "type": "ip" },
            "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" },
            "latitude" : { "type" : "half_float" },
            "longitude" : { "type" : "half_float" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anything in the configuration jump out as a potential pain point? I've tried a number of iterations of both the template file and the logstash.conf file, and now feel like I'm beating my head against the wall to no avail.